# NoMethodError in StoreController#display_cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following the book Agile Web Development with Rails - A Pragmatic Guide. On Iteration C1, creating a cart, I am getting the following error:

> ```
> NoMethodError in StoreController#display_cart
> undefined method `items' for #<Hash:0xb5cf041c>
>
> Extracted source (around line #15):
>
> 13  def display_cart
> 14    @cart = find_cart
> 15    @items = @cart.items
> 16  end
> 17
> 18 private
> ```

Here are the source files:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'store' => 'store#index'
  get 'add_item_to_cart' => 'store#add_to_cart'
  get 'display_cart' => 'store#display_cart'
  resources :products
```

store_controller.rb

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.salable_items
  end

  def add_to_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @cart = find_cart
    @cart.add_product(product)
    redirect_to display_cart_path
  end

  def display_cart
    @cart = find_cart
    @items = @cart.items
  end

  private 

    def find_cart
        session[:cart] ||= Cart.new
    end
end
```

cart.rb

```
class Cart
    attr_reader :items
    attr_reader :total_price

    def initialize
        @items = []
        @total_price = 0.0
    end

    def items
        @items
    end

    def add_product(product)
        @items << LineItem.for_product(product)
        @total_price += product.price
    end
end
```

line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product

    def self.for_product(product) 
        item = self.new
        item.quantity = 1
        item.product = product
        item.unit_price = product.price
        item
    end
end
```

I reach the action `display_cart` from the `add_to_cart` action of `StoreController`. Even though I have a `def items` in `cart.rb`, why am I getting a `NoMethodError`?

Comment: please share the code where you are setting the cart in session.

Comment: Your `find_cart` method does not return a Cart instance but a Hash. Check the described behaviour of the cart, in the great book you are working through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to return your Cart instance:

```
def find_cart
  Cart.find(session[:cart]
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  cart = Cart.new
  session[:cart] = cart.id
end
```

This is almost the same code as in your book. Semantically you could call that function `current_cart`.

By storing only the carts id and using the ActiveRecord `find()` method, rescuing with calling `Cart.new` , you will always return a cart instance.

**Edit**

if you do not implement Cart as a Model, you will (logically) never be able to instantiate an object of it.

[This](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2015/03/17/how-rails-sessions-work/) is a good article about handling sessions in Ruby on Rails. As you will see, the session itself is a Hash by 'nature', further down you will find some alternative solutions for storing sessions in your rails app.

Comment: Again, Cart is not a model. but i guess i'll implement it as one now

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have stored cart id in the session you can do following changes in your method

```
def find_cart
    Cart.find_by_id(session[:cart_id]) ||= Cart.new
end
```

Comment: Cart is not a model, but I think I'll implement it as one now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
def find_cart
    session[:cart] ||= Cart.new
end
```

your `session[:cart]` is a Hash, and thus does not get `Cart.new`, and when you call `@cart.items` it gets called on `Hash` not on a `Cart` object

Comment: @Akarsh  Could you please suggest how I can return the cart object here?

Comment: To know that, we need to see your SessionsController (which you should have if you're following the book), and show how you store the cart inside the session.

Comment: can session store objects or only key-value pairs? @the-f I've already put up all the relevant code here

Comment: @as1901 try to store id in session instead of entire hash, and then you can query for that record from Cart table.

Comment: A solution that comes to my mind is to implement cart as a model and then store the cart_id in the session

Comment: This is exactly what you want to do!

Answer (score 0):

In your display_cart method: you're doing `@cart = find_cart` which may return a hash instead of an object as in the find_cart methhod you're doing `session[:cart] ||= Cart.new` which may return a Hash.